# Inserting text values into a formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In Google Sheets, when referring to another worksheet in a formula, is there a way to insert the text value of a cell as the name of the sheet to be referenced? It is essentially a data collation table for school information, and I have separate worksheets for each class group, which auto-fills back to a common sheet in the document. I have already done this all successfully, however when creating new classes I currently have to redo all of the formulas. For ease of use, I want to have a string value in a cell on the common worksheet, use this to reference the correct sheet on the fly, and therefore need only create the new sheet and change the value in the aforementioned cell to match - thus not having to re-code all the formulas!

Let me know if I can clarify this any further.

Answer (score 0):

**`INDIRECT`** is what you seek:

```
=INDIRECT(Q2&"!A1:A2")
```

[image: 0]

```
=INDIRECT(Q$2&"!A"&ROW(A1)&":A"&ROW(A2))
```

[image: 0]